# How can I add a line for this code to ignore a cell if it contains a specific part of string?

Tags: excel, vba

My current code created a custom function to make sure email addresses contain only one "@" and at least one "." and that specific domain extensions are spelled correctly. However I want it to ignore any email containing "@'specificdomain'.org" and am curious as to how I can go about this in the most efficient way.

`````
    Dim txtEmail As String
    txtEmail = InputBox("Type the address", "e-mail address")

    Dim Situacao As String

     ' Check e-mail syntax
    If IsEmailValid(txtEmail) Then
         Situacao = "Valid e-mail syntax!"
    Else
        Situacao = "Invalid e-mail syntax!"
    End If
     ' Shows the result
    MsgBox Situacao
    End Sub
    Function IsEmailValid(strEmail)
    Dim strArray As Variant
    Dim strItem As Variant
    Dim i As Long, c As String, blnIsItValid As Boolean
    blnIsItValid = True

    i = Len(strEmail) - Len(Application.Substitute(strEmail, "@", ""))
    If i <> 1 Then IsEmailValid = False: Exit Function
    ReDim strArray(1 To 2)
    strArray(1) = Left(strEmail, InStr(1, strEmail, "@", 1) - 1)
    strArray(2) = Application.Substitute(Right(strEmail, Len(strEmail) - Len(strArray(1))), "@",   "")
    For Each strItem In strArray
        If Len(strItem) <= 0 Then
            blnIsItValid = False
            IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
            Exit Function
        End If
        For i = 1 To Len(strItem)
            c = LCase(Mid(strItem, i, 1))
            If InStr("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-.", c) <= 0 And Not IsNumeric(c) Then
                blnIsItValid = False
                IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
        If Left(strItem, 1) = "." Or Right(strItem, 1) = "." Then
            blnIsItValid = False
            IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next strItem
    If InStr(strArray(2), ".") <= 0 Then
        blnIsItValid = False
        IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
        Exit Function
    End If
    i = Len(strArray(2)) - InStrRev(strArray(2), ".")
    If i <> 2 And i <> 3 Then
        blnIsItValid = False
        IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
         Exit Function
    End If
    If InStr(strEmail, "..") > 0 Then
        blnIsItValid = False


        IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
        Exit Function
    End If
     IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
 
      If blnIsItValid = True Then
 
    ' Check if domain extension matches any in "domainExtensions"
        Dim domainExtensions As Variant
        domainExtensions = Array("com", "net", "org", "edu", "gov", "biz", "info", "online",     "site", "club", "me", "eu", "co")

        Dim isValidExtension As Boolean
        isValidExtension = False

         For i = LBound(domainExtensions) To UBound(domainExtensions)
            If Right(strEmail, Len(domainExtensions(i))) = domainExtensions(i) Then
                 isValidExtension = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

         ' Set overall validity based on both conditions
         IsEmailValid = isValidExtension

      End If
    End Function````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, a little bit depending on your needs.

a) Add a check at the end of the function.

```
If strEmail like "*@specificdomain.org" Then 
    IsEmailValid = False
End If
```

b) As the email address is valid, but you want to ignore it for other reasons, put the check into the calling code:

```
 ' Check e-mail syntax
If Not IsEmailValid(txtEmail) Then
    Situacao = "Invalid e-mail syntax!"
ElseIf txtEmail like "*@specificdomain.org" Then 
    Situacao = "Ignore e-mail syntax!"
Else
    Situacao = "Valid e-mail syntax!"
End If
```

If I where you, I would create a new function for that, even if it is only one line of code (because with that it's easier to maintain)

```
Function IsIgnoreAddress(strEmail As String) As Boolean
    IsIgnoreAddress = (strEmail like "*@specificdomain.org")
End Function
```

And then use it for example like that (again, depending on your needs)

```
 ' Check e-mail syntax
If Not IsEmailValid(txtEmail) or IsIgnoreAddress(txtEmail) Then
    Situacao = "Invalid e-mail syntax!"
Else
    Situacao = "Valid e-mail syntax!"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you , I actually put something together after posting this and was going to take it down but this is helpful for others.